# trajectory of block on incline

Tags: classical-mechanics

A block of mass m is kept at the lowest point on a wedge of mass $M$ of height $h$ and it has an angle of inclination $\theta$. The **wedge** accelerates with an acceleration $a$ such that the mass $m$ is accelerated up the incline.

What will the trajectory of the block be with respect to ground when it has reached the highest point of the wedge and is just about to lose contact with it?

All the surfaces are smooth. Additional variables to solve this question may be defined if needed, as I myself don't know if additional info is required.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbmHO.jpg)

Comment: please include $dx/dt$ and $d^2x/dt^2$ for each object so that one doesn't have to solve it like a physics problem

Comment: Unless you just pose the mathematical part in it, it will be transferred to PSE

Comment: i was told to ask this question from PSE

Comment: You should still do as much of the problem as you can. If possible, solve the problem yourself so you're just asking for confirmation or correction. Edit the question to show your work. Use MathJax: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Calling

$$
\cases{
F_a = m(a,0)\\
W=m(0,-g)\\
N=n(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
}
$$

we have

$$
F_a + W + N = m b(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)
$$

where $b$ is the acceleration module along the ramp.

Now solving for $n,b$ we obtain

$$
b = a\cos\theta-g\sin\theta
$$

so we need  $a\cos\theta>g\sin\theta$

now along the ramp, the movement follows

$$
s = \frac 12 b t^2
$$

Comment: the trajectory with respect to the groud is asked

Comment: With the elements shown, it is easy to determine the trajectory. This is left to the reader.